# Blade and Soul, Soul Shield Salvage

Tags: blade-and-soul

Is it ok to salvage the soul shield? I have too many unused soul shields in my inventory. Which Soul Shield should I not salvage or sell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is okay to salvage the soulshield pieces. More to say: you have to do this to gain materials for soulshield upgrades.

Simple scheme: salvage everyhting except the purple ones. When you get to a purple dungeon - collect it's purple soulshield set, salvage everything else. Continue to the next purple dungeon, collect it's purple soulshield set, salvage the old one and everything else. Continue up to 45 lvl.

At 45 lvl you probably will know what set do you need to farm.

Comment: Do you mean purple soulshield by its color or by its information text color? I'm in 20's level and using Viridian Valor Soul Shield

Comment: I mean the color of the text. Viridian Valor is blue, if I recall correctly.